# How to detect Pentagons and Hexagons in EmguCv

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, emgucv

I'm doing a project to identify basic geometric shapes using emgucv. I'm using following code to identify pentagon shapes. but when I execute it, it shows pentagons and circles also. I want only pentagons as the output. I have already done identifying circles,rectangles and triangles. How to display only pentagons using this code?
Thank you!

```
    public Image<Bgr, Byte> My_Image;
    public Image<Gray, Byte> grayImage;
    public Image<Gray, Byte> cannyEdges;      

    grayImage = My_Image.Convert<Gray, byte>();



public void CannyEdgeDetection()
         {
            try
            {
                double cannyThresholdLinking = 120.0;
                cannyEdges = grayImage.Canny(cannyThreshold, cannyThresholdLinking);
                lines = cannyEdges.HoughLinesBinary(
                    1, //Distance resolution in pixel-related units
                    Math.PI / 45.0, //Angle resolution measured in radians.
                    20, //threshold
                    10, //min Line width
                    10 //gap between lines
                    )[0]; //Get the lines from the first channel
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

         }

    public void DetectPentagons()
            {

                try
                {

                    CannyEdgeDetection();

                    using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage())
                        for (
                          Contour<Point> contours = cannyEdges.FindContours(
                              Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
                              Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,
                              storage);
                           contours != null;
                           contours = contours.HNext)
                        {
                            Contour<Point> currentContour = contours.ApproxPoly(contours.Perimeter * 0.05, storage);

                            if (currentContour.Area > 100)
                            {
                                if (currentContour.Total == 5) 
                                {

                                    grayImage.Draw(contours, new Bgr(Color.Red), 10);
                                    pictureBox2.Image = obj.grayImage.Bitmap;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Side note: `catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }` is worse than useless, because it wipes out the stack trace. If you're not going to meaningfully handle an exception, you are better off not catching it - just remove the try/catch block entirely. If you want to be able to set a breakpoint there or log it or something, then just call `throw;`, not `throw ex`, and the stack-trace will remain intact.

Comment: ok got it. Do you know how to display only pentagons using this code instead of other shapes?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on number of segments of a contour to detect a shape, since the contour found will be aliased (jagged), and any polygon approximation ("smoothing") can change the contour too much.

One feature that you can use to detect shapes is [circularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_factor_(image_analysis_and_microscopy)#Circularity). Circularity is a factor that determines how closely the shape is to a circle.

```
circularity ~= 1, shape is a circle
circularity < 1, shape is convex
circularity > 1, shape is concave
```

The formula for it is:

```
circularity = (4 * PI * contour_area) / contour_perimeter ^ 2
```

Every shape has it's own expected circularity value, for example, a square should have a circularity of 0.7853, and you can use this value to filter contours for squares. You should have every value available from the FindContours method.